# NextJS 13 returns response via api testing client but not in frontend

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm on something extremely simple and can't seem to find a straight forward answer.

I have an API route:

```
// /api/test/route.js
export async function GET(request, response) {
  console.log("requested");
  return NextResponse.json({ my: "data" });
}
```

And a component that issues a request to the endpoint on a button click (I've put the headers in intentionally to troubleshoot the issue):

```
// /components/client/test.js
"use client";

export default function ExampleClientComponent({children}) {

  async function handleClick() {
    let data = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/test", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    });
    console.log("data", data);
  }
   
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Go</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

And when the button is clicked I see confirmation via console log the request was made and get the following 200 response in browser. The body is as a `ReadableStrea`m which from what I have read is the default response for HTTP Responses. However, my understanding of `NextResponse` is that it should return the response as JSON.

```
Response
body: ReadableStream {locked: false}
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {append: function, delete: function, get: function, has: function, set: function, …}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost:3000/api/test"
```

When I test the end point I get a JSON body

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
connection: close
content-encoding: gzip
content-type: application/json
date: Tue, 25 Jul 2023 23:15:42 GMT
transfer-encoding: chunked
vary: RSC, Next-Router-State-Tree, Next-Router-Prefetch, Accept-Encoding

{
    "my": "data"
}
```

What is going on here? Tutorials and documentation I read (admittedly has been related to POST requests rather than GET) seems to suggest this would work. The outcome I expect is that the request returns a response with a JSON body.

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to do?

Comment: Simply receive the response in json to use on a page. I had just missed including .json() on the response. The answer is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fetch() method returns a Promise. If you want to access the response from the endpoint, you can do it like this.

```js
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/test", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    });
const data = await response.json();
console.log(data);
```

If you want to find out more, here is a link to the docs.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Of course, I've completely overlooked the handling of the requested and focus on the response. Thanks